# How to make JQuery mobile panel always remain a part of that showing on page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Here's the problem, I want some part of JQuery mobile Panel always showing on page in order to add a button to show/hide the panel on the always-showing part. Is it related to adjust the animation length in the CSS?

Could anyone show me a simple demo? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please provide more information??? or a jsfiddle

Comment: http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Sliding-Sidebar-Menu-jQuery-Sidebar/#    The effect should be like this, always showing an arrow to control the sidebar.But is it possible to modify the Jquery mobile panel to something like this?

Comment: what did you try ? where do you get stuck ?

Comment: Are there any properties to modify the moving distance of the panel? I checked documentation on http://api.jquerymobile.com/panel/, but still didn't have a clue.

Answer (score 1):

I also encounter such a problem. Here is my solution:
add the following javascript into your header:
    $(document).on("pagebeforeshow", function( event, data ) {
        $('#my-panel').panel("open");
    })

and in your panel add two attributes:data-swipe-close="false" , data-dismissible="false"

then the panel will be also shown in your html